# Sql Server get time since in "X Seconds/Minutes/Hours/Days" format

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am working on SQL SERVER 2016. I need to show time passed since the last action to user. It should in format like "Last action was 3 minutes ago" or "Last action was 5 days ago". I need dynamic datepart for intervals because I am not knowing how much time has passed. System should get time interval(if it is under one hour, it must be minutes. If it is less than a day it should be hours) and time passed in that interval format(like 3 hour ago or 1 day ago).

I write this for now

```
FORMAT(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MAX(myDate),GETDATE()), 'MINUTE' , 'en-US')
```

but it's result is

> "Last action was MINUTE ago"

and also I would like to get time in other formats like "5 days ago" or "4 hours ago" if time interval has changed.

How can I achieve this, I couldn't find the right `datediff` interval and `FORMAT`

Comment: Do you know `DATEPART` (for units of time) and `CONCAT` (for concatenating VARCHARs)?

Comment: *"I am working on SQL SERVER 2016"* Then please don't tag [tag:mysql]. SQL Server and MySQL are completely different RDBMS.

Comment: As for your question, the RDBMS should be working out the difference (in minutes) here, so the value `3`, and the application layer should be doing the rest, and making it into a sentence.

Comment: @deHaar I know that functions but they are not working for my problem. I need dynamic datepart for intervals because I am not knowing how much time has passed. System should get time time interval(if it is under one hour, it must be minutes. If it is less than a day it should be hours) and time passed  in that interval(like 3 hour ago or 1 day ago).

Comment: What exactly is your requirement? Is it a result in a single column (a concatenated VARCHAR)? Or would it be sufficient to have one column per unit of time to be considered?

Comment: @AlpUygur Check my edited answer, I added a different approach, maybe it is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select 'Last action was '
       (case when datediff(day, MAX(myDate), GETDATE()) > 0
             then concat(datediff(day, MAX(myDate), GETDATE()), ' day(s) ago')
             when datediff(hour, MAX(myDate), GETDATE()) > 0
             then concat(datediff(hour, MAX(myDate), GETDATE()), ' hours(s) ago')
             when datediff(minute, MAX(myDate), GETDATE()) > 0
             then concat(datediff(minute, MAX(myDate), GETDATE()), ' minute(s) ago')
             when datediff(second, MAX(myDate), GETDATE()) > 0
             then concat(datediff(second, MAX(myDate), GETDATE()), ' second(s) ago')
             else 'Just happened!'
         end)
```

The `case` is starting at the largest unit (days) and checking if that applies.

Actually, `datediff()` may not be what you want.  It aligns to calendar days.  So, "1 day ago" really means "yesterday" regardless of time.  Perhaps a more accurate method would be:

```
select 'Last action was '
       (case when dateadd(day, 1, MAX(myDate) < GETDATE()
             then concat(datediff(day, MAX(myDate), GETDATE()), ' day(s) ago')
             when dateadd(hour, 1, MAX(myDate)) < GETDATE())
             then concat(datediff(hour, MAX(myDate), GETDATE()), ' hours(s) ago')
             when dateadd(minute, 1, MAX(myDate)) < GETDATE()
             then concat(datediff(minute, MAX(myDate), GETDATE()), ' minute(s) ago')
             when dateadd(second, 1, MAX(myDate)) < GETDATE())
             then concat(datediff(second, MAX(myDate), GETDATE()), ' second(s) ago')
             else 'Just happened!'
         end)
```

This guarantees that there is at least one entire unit in the past before choosing that unit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses `CONCAT` and some hard-coded values for producing an output as required in your question:

```sql
SELECT
    CONCAT('Last Action was ',
            DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2020-10-07T11:06:22', '2020-10-07T11:07:22'),
            ' MINUTE ago'
    ) AS "Elapsed"
```

The output is

```
|         Elapsed            |
------------------------------
|Last Action was 1 MINUTE ago|
```

You will have to replace those hard coded timestamps by the values of your choice and the interval of the `DATEDIFF` function as well if you want different units to be considered.

Another possible solution would be this:

```sql
SELECT
    'Last Action was ' +
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, '2020-10-07T11:06:22', '2020-10-08T11:07:22') > 0
        THEN CONCAT(DATEDIFF(DAY, '2020-10-07T11:06:22', '2020-10-08T11:07:22'), ' DAY(S)')
        ELSE ''
    END +
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, '2020-10-07T11:06:22', '2020-10-08T11:07:22') % 24 > 0
        THEN CONCAT(DATEDIFF(HOUR, '2020-10-07T11:06:22', '2020-10-08T11:07:22') % 24, ' HOUR(S)')
        ELSE ''
    END + ' and ' +
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2020-10-07T11:06:22', '2020-10-08T11:07:22') % 60 > 0
        THEN CONCAT(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2020-10-07T11:06:22', '2020-10-08T11:07:22') % 60, ' MINUTE(S) ago')
        ELSE ''
    END AS "Message"
```

which outputs

```
|                  Message                     |
------------------------------------------------
| Last Action was 1 DAY(S) and 1 MINUTE(S) ago |
```

As you can see, the hours are not mentioned in the result column because their value would be exactly 24 hours, which is already printed by one day.

You will have to fiddle around in order to get every possible result in the form *Last Action was 2 hours and 1 minute ago* or *Last Action was 1 day, 2 hours and 1 minute ago*...